# removing lines from the start of a csv file, python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Say I have the following file:

> ```
> student.id, student.name, student.is_male, student.birth_date, student.courseid, student.gradeid 
> 90, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 5
> 91, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 1
> 92, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 2, 8
> 93, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 7
> 94, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 1
> 95, 'Pat', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 4, 2
> 96, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 7
> 97, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 4, 6
> 98, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 4, 7
> 99, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 1
> 100, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 2
> 101, 'Pat', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 5
> 102, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 7
> 103, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 4, 5
> 104, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 2, 8
> 105, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 9
> 106, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 7
> 107, 'Pat', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 2, 8
> 108, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 3
> 109, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 9
> 110, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 4
> 111, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 4
> 112, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 1
> 113, 'Pat', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 8
> 114, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 4, 2
> 115, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 2, 5
> 116, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 5
> 117, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 8
> 118, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 9
> 119, 'Pat', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 8
> 120, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 1
> 121, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 4, 3
> 122, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 3
> 123, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 5
> 124, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 5
> 125, 'Pat', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 1
> 126, 'Jeff', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 9
> 127, 'Allan', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 5, 6
> 128, 'Maria', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 2, 5
> 129, 'Lucie', False, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 1, 2
> 130, 'John', True, datetime.date(2014, 8, 5), 3, 8
> ```

In python, I want to read the header line and first 20 lines into a list of dictionaries, with : as the key:value pairs in each dictionary. I want then to update the file contents, to retain the header and following lines while dropping the processed lines.

how do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect job for a Pandas data frame. It will make your life much easier for whatever you are trying to do here.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('your.csv')
```

There are then many convenient (and fast) ways to manipulate the data and access specific rows and indices.

check out the docs here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html